# vim: alias yank and copy to xclip

Tags: vim

I've got a `cntrl c` and `cntrl v` mapped to xclip, however its a hassle to have to remember to use instead of regular `y` and `p`. Is there a way to alias the two or send contents of `y` and `p` to xclip, so I can just use `y` and `p` for all copy and pasting?

```
vmap <C-c> y:call system("xclip -i -selection clipboard", getreg("\""))<CR>:call system("xclip -i", getreg("\""))<CR>
nmap <C-v> :call setreg("\"",system("xclip -o -selection clipboard"))<CR>p")")")"))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you trying to use the X clipboard for all copy and pastes?  If so, a good alternative to xclip is to make sure you're using a vim with X support (it's really easy to compile Vim if your version doesn't have it) and then add the following to your vimrc:

```
set clipboard=unnamed
```

All yanks and deletes will then automatically go to the `*` register (which is the X selection register).

Instead of setting `clipboard=unnamed`, you can also use the X selection register for a single operation by using (e.g.)

```
"*yw
"*yy
"*ya(
```

or whatever.

Obviously, this doesn't answer your question as to how to use xclip, but hopefully it offers an alternative approach.

Comment: Actually I just replace the `<C-c>` and `<C-v>` with `y` and `p` and it seems to work, although pasting after pressing `p` seems to take a while, not sure why.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this is an ideal solution, but it works.

```
set clipboard=unnamedplus

function! ClipboardYank()
  call system('wl-copy || xclip -i -selection clipboard', @@)
endfunction

let vlcb = 0
let vlce = 0
function! ClipboardPaste(mode)
  if (a:mode == "v")
    call cursor(g:vlcb[0], g:vlcb[1]) | execute "normal! v" | call cursor(g:vlce[0], g:vlce[1])  
  endif
  let @@ = system('wl-paste >/dev/null 2>/dev/null && wl-paste -n || xclip -o -selection clipboard')
endfunction

" replace currently selected text with default register without yanking it
vnoremap <silent>p "_dP

vnoremap <silent>y y:call ClipboardYank()<CR>
vnoremap <silent>d d:call ClipboardYank()<CR>
nnoremap <silent>dd dd:call ClipboardYank()<CR>

nnoremap <silent>p :call ClipboardPaste("n")<CR>p
vnoremap p :<C-U>let vlcb = getpos("'<")[1:2] \| let vlce = getpos("'>")[1:2] \| call ClipboardPaste("v")<CR>p
```

This works with both X and Wayland.

Comment: Works very well for me, thanks. Except I like to have the default X selection (on GNU/Linux), so I just skipped the `-selection clipboard` from the xclip command line. Also, the double keybindings are not working for me, but that's probably coming from my `timeoutlen=50` settings (which is needed for another hack).

Comment: I've improved the example for automatic switching between X and Wayland.

Answer (score -1):

You can also `set clipboard=unnamedplus` to use the “+” register by default. Using it, I did yy in my .vimrc and then pasted that line here by ctrl-V ;)